# Get image dimension from images in folder with php

Tags: php, mysql, dimensions, getimagesize

I got a question. I need to get the image dimensions from images in folder with PHP. I know that probably would be the best way to do this with PHP function `getimagesize` but I have no idea where to put the piece of code into my script in order to save to DB. Could you please help me out.
Here is my Php Script:

```
<?php      

$server = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'password';
$dbname = 'dbname';

$connect = mysql_connect($server,$dbuser,$dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname,$connect);

$path = "gb-bilder-pics/augen/";
$files = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string',array_filter(glob("{$path}*.*"),'is_file'));
if(empty($files)){
    echo "There were no matching files to insert into the database.";
}else{  
    $insertValues = array();
foreach($files as $file)
{
    $insertValues[] = "('Titel', 'augen', '{$file}', '{$width????}', '{$height????}')";
}$query = "INSERT INTO `gbpics` (`gbpictitel`, `gbpiccat`, `gbpicurl`, `gbpicwidth`, `gbpicheight`) VALUES " . implode(', ', $insertValues);
    if(!mysql_query($query)){
        echo "There was a problem inserting the data.";
        trigger_error("Query failed: $query<br />Error: " . mysql_error());
    } else {
        echo "The data was inserted successfully.";
    }
}?>
```

Comment: Have you googled "php image size"? The MySQL extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0.

Comment: yes have googled i use php 5.6 so would be okay

Comment: or is there an alternative ? when i switch to php 7?

Comment: getimagesize will work fine on PHP 7.0 according to PHP.net.
Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

Comment: The obvious alternative is to use php version 7 and to port your code to the more secure mysql adapters `mysqli` or `PDO`. You will have to do that anyway, so get started _now_.

Answer (score 1):

> (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7) getimagesize — Get the size of an image

Simply use `getimagesize` and pass the filename. It will return the dimensions along with the file type and height/width text string.

I suggest trying out this function on an image you have on your computer and just look at how the method behaves. I'm sure you will be able to figure out how to extract the width and height from the result.

If you afterwards still need help implementing it in your own code then don't be afraid to ask.

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)

Comment: Hey got a function which could do the job but i cant figure out how to implement he gives me an error message `getimagesize() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/ud20_182/html/gbpicscom/upload-from-folder-in-database.php on line 27` @Arjan

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out was really easy this is the script modified to get image dimensions without the db connection which u have to place before if u want to use the script on your server.

```
$path = "gb-bilder-pics/augen/";
$files = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string',array_filter(glob("{$path}*.*"),'is_file'));

if(empty($files)){
    echo "There were no matching files to insert into the database.";
} else {    
    $insertValues = array();
foreach($files as $file)

{
$data = getimagesize($file);
$width = $data[0];
$height = $data[1];
    $insertValues[] = "('Titel', 'augen', '{$file}', '$width', '$height')";
}$query = "INSERT INTO `gbpics` (`gbpictitel`, `gbpiccat`, `gbpicurl`, `gbpicwidth`, `gbpicheight`) VALUES " . implode(', ', $insertValues);
    if(!mysql_query($query)){
        echo "There was a problem inserting the data.";
        trigger_error("Query failed: $query<br />Error: " . mysql_error());
    } else {
        echo "The data was inserted successfully.";
    }
}
```